# Amazon S3 or similar object store for Dedicated server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am going to launch a few rails applications, I decided to go with dedicated servers mainly because of the cost advantages.

But, I would like to have a proper object store setup for storing user uploaded files and images, to avoid complexity down the line during migrating servers and such.

Can I use amazon s3 and RDS with dedicated servers? If that is not possilbe, is there an object storage service that works nice with Dedicated servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use S3 from any server, it doesn't need to be hosted on Amazon EC2 for S3 to work. Same goes for RDS.

But keep in mind that the quality of the internet connection between your current hosting provider and the AWS endpoints will affect your app's performance. If the latency and speed of this connection is an issue, it would probably be better to host your app on EC2.

Comment: Side note: One difference between using S3 from an EC2 server and a non-AWS server is that you will be billed for bandwidth on objects your *server* fetches from S3 if your server isn't an EC2 server.  Fetching objects from S3 to an EC2 server in the same AWS region does not incur bandwidth charges.  Uploads into S3 don't incur bandwidth charges in any configuration, and downloads to client browsers from S3 do incur bandwidth charges in all configurations, so the only difference is whether your server directly fetches objects from S3.